# Optimalize sql transactions in API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Recently I had an job interview and I got little homework. Then I got feedback, that I have unnecessary combination of query and transaction in update endpoint.

```
export const update = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const reportId = parseInt(req.params.id)
        const { name, age, info } = req.body

        const report = await ReportModel.findOne({
            where: {
                id: reportId
            }
        })
        if (!report) return next(new EntityNotExistError("Report doesn't exists"))

        await ReportModel.update({
            name,
            age,
            info
        }, {
            where: {
                id: reportId
            }
        })

        const _report = await ReportModel.findOne({
            where: {
                id: reportId
            }
        })

        return res.json({
            message: "The report was successfully edited",
            report: _report
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first query check if entity exists, then I make an update of the entity and last query return updated entity.
Is there some way how to optimalize comunication with database?